# A Parameter is missing. [Parameter ordinal =8]

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

```cs
Query = "update Product set ProductName=@ProductName,Specification=@Specification" +
",DepartmentId=@DepartmentId,UnitId=@UnitId,TCategoryId=@TCategoryId,HSNId=@HSNId,SGroupId=@SGroupId" + " where ProductCode=@ProductCode";

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConnection))

                    {

                        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, con))

                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", strSpecification);
                            
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", strDepartmentId);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitId", strUnitId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCategoryId", strTCategoryId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSNId", strHSNId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SGroupId", strSGroupId);

                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You need to pass `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`, so for each of the parameters you would do something like `strSGroupId ?? (object) DBNull.Value`. And you [shouldn't use `AddWIthValue` anyway](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), specify your parameter types and lengths explicitly. Also `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` is unnecessary, it is a new command object.

Comment: Please add proper explanation and code snippets or errors that you are facing.

Comment: @Charlieface doesnot work

Comment: @PrathameshMore its as mentioned sir

Comment: @Charlieface sir it gets successfully updated though it passes error

Answer (score 0):

Query = "update Product set ProductName=@ProductName,Specification=@Specification" +
",DepartmentId=@DepartmentId,UnitId=@UnitId,TCategoryId=@TCategoryId,HSNId=@HSNId,SGroupId=@SGroupId" +
" where ProductCode=@ProductCode";
if (Properties.Settings.Default.isCompact)
{
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConnection))
{
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, con))
{
cmd.Parameters.Clear();

```
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", strSpecification);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", strDepartmentId);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitId", strUnitId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCategoryId", strTCategoryId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSNId", strHSNId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SGroupId", strSGroupId);

                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", dgvAdjustment.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToUpper());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", strSpecification);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitId", strUnitId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", strDepartmentId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCategoryId", strTCategoryId);


                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSNId", strHSNId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SGroupId", strSGroupId);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

               // DbUpdate(Query);

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "ESoft");
            loadItems();
            loadDataGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I have called cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); anothertime in DbUpdate(Query);

Comment: so i commented DbUpdate(Query);